# How to sql sort the table in classic asp where data is retrieved from database?

Tags: asp-classic, tablesorter

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
        } 
    ); 
</script>
```

```vbscript
<html>
    <head>
    <div id="main">
    <%
    SET RS = objconn.execute(SQL)
    IF NOT RS.EOF THEN
        Response.Write "<table id= 'myTable' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='1px'>"
        Response.Write "<tr>"
        Response.Write "<td class='tdcell1' colspan='1'>"
        Response.Write "ID"
        Response.Write "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td class='tdcell1' colspan='1'>"
        Response.Write "Date"
        Response.Write "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td class='tdcell1' colspan='1'>"
        Response.Write "Title"
        Response.Write "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td class='tdcell1' colspan='1'>"
        Response.Write "Author"
        Response.Write "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td class='tdcell1' colspan='1'>"
        Response.Write "Image Name"
        Response.Write "</td>"
        Response.Write "</tr>"
        While NOT RS.EOF
            Response.Write "<tr>"
            Response.Write "<td class='tdcell' colspan='1'>"
            Response.Write RS("id")
            Response.Write "</td>"
            Response.Write "<td class='tdcell' colspan='1'>"
            Response.Write RS("launchdate")
            Response.Write "</td>"
            Response.Write "<td class='tdcell' colspan='1'>"
            Response.Write RS("title")
            Response.Write "</td>"
            Response.Write "<td class='tdcell' colspan='1'>"
            Response.Write RS("firstname") & " " & RS("lastname")
            Response.Write "</td>"
            Response.Write "<td class='tdcell' colspan='1'>"
            Response.Write RS("bimg")
            Response.Write "</td>"
            Response.Write "</tr>"
            RS.Movenext
        Wend
        Response.Write "</table>"
    END IF
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
END IF
%>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to sort a table's date (by ascending and descending) and author name alphabetically. I have heard of "table sorter plugin" but I think it's for a standard html table only because I failed when I tried it. Attached is the code I am working on which doesn't work. I kept just to let you all know what and how I am working. I expected the date header with nice small arrow for sorting but couldn't get it.

Comment: Tablesorter requires a `thead` and `tbody` before it will initialize on a table. Try setting the `debug:true` option to watch for errors.

Comment: Thanks alot @mottie for replying. I am still a beginner programmer so I didn't knew about it.  Ya i added thead and tbody but still it doesn't work. Is there specific place to keep debug:true ?

Comment: `$("#myTable").tablesorter({ debug: true });`, then open the development console (press F12).

Comment: 1. As far as jquery/javascript is concerned, your table ***is*** a "standard html table". You'll need to check the documentation for the plugin you're trying to use to figure out what hooks they expect - i.e. what ID to give the table, how to tell the plugin which columns are sortable, etc. 2. Lose the `colspan='1'` - it serves no purpose other than to clutter up your code. 3. If you find yourself having to add a class to every single cell of a table, you need to rethink your CSS.